# Thieves guild radiant quest glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I finish the thieves guild questline, but I can't seem to get more than $200 when I completed the radiant quests from Vex or Delvin. In an old account I was able to get $400 from these radiant quests after I finished the questline but now I can't.
Is this some kind of glitch?

Comment: I think this has to do with your current level? i.e. The higher your player level, the more money you make.

Answer (score 2):

The lower the level you are the less gold you get from contracts. Your old acc was probably a higher level that your new one.